# Waiting for response from factory then proceed to service call

Tags: angularjs

I want the `service(MyService.postData)` to be call only after all the functionality in factory function(`MyFactory.getData`) is over.

The return value from factory is always false or undefined and I get an error for sending the service call:

**1.** First am calling a function define in factory which is used for login in a user through a pop up template

**2.** Secondly, only if user is logged in, the following service call will be made:

```
    //My AngularJS controller is something like 
    myApp.controller("firstCtrl", function($scope, MyFactory, MyService) { 
        $scope.value = MyFactory.getData();
        if($scope.value){
            MyService.postData("url",params).then(function(){
                //do something
            });

    });

    //My AngularJS factory is something like
    myApp.factory("MyFactory",function(){
         return {
             getData: function(){
                //open pop up to login 
                //close pop up get confirmation
                return true;
             }
    });

    //My AngularJS service is something like
    myApp.service("MyService",function($http){
    //do something
    });
```

Comment: The getData in the factory should be promise-based. Then you can move the call MyService.postData inside its then block.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `$http`?

```
myApp.factory("MyService", ["$http", function($http){
    return {
        getData: function(url) {
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        postData: function(url, payload) {
            return $http.post(url, payload);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Then**

```
myService.getData(url).then(function(response) {
    var payload = {
        item: response.data.someItem;
    };
    var url2 = '/path/to/somewhere/';

    myService.postData(url2, payload).then(function(response) {
        alert('ok');
    }).catch(function(response) {
        alert('error2');
    });
}).catch(function(response) {
        alert('error1');
});
```

Comment: No I am not using http in my factory, all my service call are from service.

Comment: Why does `postData()` and `getData()` live in two different places?

Comment: Get data is just a random name imagine it as it check for login which open a pop that's it.  The whole logic is in a different controller.  My factory only store and update values.  On the other hand my service does all the service call